# Magento 2 - find out if text is from static block

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, template, cms, static-block

I try to replace the footer with my own, but I have no clue how.

I activated template hints, but it does not show any hint if this is a static block.

[image]

How can I modify this ?

Comment: That is not static block but that links you can add same as My account dashboard section.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: You want to update any links or you want to add/remove links ?

Comment: I want to add/remove links.

Comment: I've added my answer with output, let me know if you want any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this file in `vendor` directory.

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

In above file `footer_links` block created under `footer-container` section. In default **Luma theme** you can see below five links in footer section.

- Search Terms
- Privacy and Cookie Policy
- Advanced Search
- Orders and Returns
- Contact Us

All above links are coming from different files.

**Search Terms** link coming from this file..

> vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

**Privacy and Cookie Policy** link from..

> vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

and so on..

If you want to remove any link or you want to update link's action URL/Path then you need to create `default.xml` file in your custom module or custom theme.

For e.g. if you want to remove "**Search Terms**" link and you want to update label of "**Orders and Returns**" to "**Returns**" and you want to add new link then you can do this..

Create `default.xml` file here in your custom theme.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true" /> <!-- This will remove "Search Terms" link -->
      <referenceBlock name="footer_links"> <!-- This block will change label from "Orders and Returns" to "Returns" -->
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Guest\Link" name="sales-guest-form-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Returns</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/guest/form</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- Below code is useful to add new "Custom link" in footer links -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="new-custom-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Custom Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">new/custom/url</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It really helped me to understand it.

Comment: You're most welcome buddy! :)

Comment: I have one question left. How did you knew that you have to use **search-term-popular-link** for referenceBlock?

Comment: You can find that block in this xml file.   vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: Ok the question was more like, how did you know that you have to search in this module. But I guess you just took the url path `search/term/popular` and searched it in all modules.

Comment: First of all I see the link start with search so that is relevant to Search modules, so I go to vendor/magento /module-search directory and confirmed it's router for frontend. After that I checked XML files. Same thing you can do for contact us link that is relevant to contact module.

Comment: Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

It's a block (name: *footer_links*) which just render set of children blocks, base declaration you can find in vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml:123

How to add new link:

```
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms" name="search-term-popular-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search Terms</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">search/term/popular</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

How to remove link:

```
<referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true" />
```

which will remove first link on your screen.